# More effective way to append json data with jQuery & Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, append

I am building a twitter style feed with Laravel and jQuery.

My problem is that I'm sure I built this logic up badly.

So I have an included view what shows the tweet results.

Sending the data is just a basic ajax post with some DOM manipulation that's fine too.

After the form is submitted I display the fresh tweet with and **append**.

But the problem is no matter how i build my logic up, i always end up with duplication.

So what I do

Send the form, and the success function appends the data to the view

```
success: function(data) {

                if(data.status === "success") {
                    $('#tweet-textarea').val("");
                    $('#tweets-wrapper').prepend(data.content);
                }
            },
```

And returning the goes the following way. After the tweet is saved, I return it in an array what I encode to json

```
$data = array('status' => 'success', 'content' => 
                '<div class="tweet-box">
                    <div class="media">
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
                      </a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">
                            '. $this->tweet->user->metadata->full_name .'
                            <small>'. "@".$this->tweet->user->username .'</small>
                            <small>'. $this->tweet->created_at .'</small>
                        </h4>
                       '.  $this->tweet->message .'
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>');
```

I know not the best way, and my problem is actually in my controller I am duplicating code, because the returned result *"content in array"* is the same just like in my view, so if I make any modification I need to make both

So is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: You send the data not the HTML, and have one template that is used for both server-side and client-side, or just client-side if you render this in the client the first time too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery jPut Plugin to append json easily

```
<div jput="template">
  <div class="tweet-box">
                    <div class="media">
                      <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
                      </a>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{{}}</h4>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="main">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//main is the div that you want to append
   $('#main').jPut({
       ajax_url:'domain.com/data.json',   //your json data page
       name:'template'  //jPut template name
   });
});
</script>
```

And in you json page no need to send all the div

```
$data = array('status' => 'success', 'content' => $this->tweet->user->metadata->full_name);
```

Comment: Posting a link to a page is not an answer to a question. Please post code showing how this would work in this instance, or leave a comment on the question with the link.

Comment: still not solves my problem, i cant use a plugin always for every problem

Comment: @LeventeNagy if you want to solve this easily & to reduce the code you should use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplication of code, you are going to have to take all that logic out of your view and just pass it a nice long string for the entire section from your controller.

I'd start with making a function which can take a full name, username, timestamp, and message and create the tweet.

```
public function createTweet($fullName, $username, $created_at, $message)
{
    return  '<div class="tweet-box">
                <div class="media">
                  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                   <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        '. $full_name .'
                        <small>'. "@".$username .'</small>
                        <small>'. $created_at .'</small>
                    </h4>
                   '.  $message .'
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
}
```

Then when you are looping through your tweets, call this function each time through and keep concatenating the response in a string, then you can just pass the string to your view and echo it there.

On your function which is returning ajax, do the same...

```
return Respons::json(array(
    'status' => 'success', 
    'content' => $this->createTweet($this->tweet->user->metadata->full_name, $this->tweet->user->username, $this->tweet->created_at, $this->tweet->message)
));
```

You could also take a lot at `HTML::macro()` as well if you find yourself needing this functionality across your entire app.  http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/181 for a nice and quick `HTML::macro()` tut.

Comment: i was thinking to use Macros at the first place, i think i will just use a simple function